# OpenSearch implement QueryByUpdate with query and script tag using Java Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch

query :-

```
POST demo_index/_update_by_query
{
 "query" : {
      "terms" : {
          "_id" :[
                "123"
               ]
             }
},
"script" : {
   "source" : "if (cox._source.time < params.time ) { cox.source.time = 8;}",
   "lang": "painless",
   "params" : {
       "time" : 2,
       "acctId" : "999",
       "hash" : "rqwtqw"
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to implement this in OpenSearch using Java Client but couldn't figure out how to use Script.Builder for creating script data.

I did find some examples of ElasticSearch but I guess classes are different in OpenSearch so not able to use that same classes

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the UpdateByQueryRequest.
i.e. :

```
//loading the script
Map<String,Object> scriptParams = Maps.of("some arg", "some arg value");
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, 
Script.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_LANG, "your painless script", scriptParams); //default lang is PAINLESS
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = ... your query ..;
UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest()
            .setQuery(queryBuilder)
            .setScript(script);
//sending the update by query request
osClient.updateByQuery(updateByQueryRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```